# How can i make selenium wait till the next page is loaded with same URL and have same fields

Tags: selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, wait

I have this code show below:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("submit")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER); 
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.findElement(By.id("search-trigger")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
driver.findElement(By.id("search-trigger")).sendKeys("Shampoo");
driver.findElement(By.id("search-trigger")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```

I want to search for a product and search option is before and after login page but here i want to do it after login page
I have used

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

but it doesn't work and i cannot use

```
WebElement  “”= driver.findElement(By.id(""));
```

as the search option is on both pages 
and URL remains same after login also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per my understanding, in short, you want to ensure user has logged in before searching for a product. However u will not be able to use WebElement  “”= driver.findElement(By.id(""));

Did you try explicit wait for the presence of username/logout text...etc

```
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementIsVisible(By.id(>someid>)));
```

Below worked for me, tried searching Samsung after login in flipkart:

```
public static void f() throws InterruptedException
{       
    By signin = By.xpath(".//*[@id='container']/div/header/div[1]/div[1]/div/ul/li[9]/a");
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    By mobile = By.xpath("html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/form/div[1]/input");
    By password = By.xpath("html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/form/div[2]/input");
    By login = By.xpath("html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/form/div[3]/button");
    By myaccount = By.xpath(".//*[@id='container']/div/header/div[1]/div[1]/div/ul/li[8]/a");
    By search = By.xpath(".//*[@id='container']/div/header/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/form/div/div[1]/div/input");    
    //geko driver for firefox
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "path of geckodriver.exe");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "path of chromedriver.exe");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();

    driver.get("https://www.flipkart.com/");
    driver.findElement(signin).click();;
    driver.findElement(mobile).sendKeys("xxxxxxxxx");
    driver.findElement(password).sendKeys("xxxxxxxx");
    driver.findElement(login).click();

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait (driver, 10);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(myaccount));
    driver.findElement(search).sendKeys("samsung");     
}
```